# Thymeleaf not loading html pages except index.html Spring boot 3.0.2

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

[index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qAXN.png)i have created project through spring.io .  I am integrating thyme leaf 3.0.2 in spring boot 3.0.2 using java jdk 19 and IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 (Community Edition) . Spring boot not loading page except index.html . When i run app index page loads fine but as i click on register button ehite label error occurs images are attached   . I have gone throw many tutorials but not fund any solution could anyone give a solution . Regards

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>web demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

HomeController

```
package com.example.web.controller;

import com.example.web.dto.UserDto;
import com.example.web.models.User;
import com.example.web.service.UserService;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String home(){
        return "index";
    }
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String showRegistrationForm(Model model){
        // create model object to store form data
        UserDto user = new UserDto();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "register";
    }
    @PostMapping("/register/save")
    public String registration(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") UserDto userDto,
                               BindingResult result,
                               Model model){
        User existingUser = userService.findUserByEmail(userDto.getEmail());

        if(existingUser != null && existingUser.getEmail() != null && !existingUser.getEmail().isEmpty()){
            result.rejectValue("email", null,
                    "There is already an account registered with the same email");
        }

        if(result.hasErrors()){
            model.addAttribute("user", userDto);
            return "/register";
        }

        userService.saveUser(userDto);
        return "redirect:/register?success";
    }
}
```

WebDemoApplication (main class)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

[Directory Structure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjhpE.png)

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVaMm.png)

[whitelabel error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZLdk.png)

Comment: Do you have any spaces in the path of your application's location on the file system? If so, you are probably being affected by [this regression](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30031) in Spring Framework and you should upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.4 to pick up the fix.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Following is my path
D:\Java\demo (3)\demo can u plz help

Comment: Kudos to @AndyWilkinson. Solved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're being affected by a regression in Spring Framework that caused problems with applications with a space in their path. You can fix the problem by upgrading to Spring Boot 3.0.4. To do so, update your pom's parent:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

You should also remove the version from your dependency on `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This will allow its version to be managed by `spring-boot-starter-parent` and ensure that its version is in sync with other Spring Boot modules.